# Por que estou recebendo o retorno "0" independentemente da entrada inserida?

Tags: c, funções

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Comparacao(int x, int y){

    int resultado;
    if(x < y){
        resultado = -1;
    }else{
        if(x == y){
            resultado = 0;
        }else{
            resultado = 1;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

int main(){

    int a=0, b=0;

    puts("Digite um valor para a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    puts("Digite um valor para b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    Comparacao(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O maior problema é que não está imprimindo o resultado, ele está sendo retornado. Retorno e impressão são coisas diferentes. O código estava descartando o resultado que a função restornava.

Mas eu respondi mais porque dá para fazer um código muito mais simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Comparacao(int x, int y)  {
    return x < y ? -1 : x != y;
}

int main(){
    int a, b;
    puts("Digite um valor para a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    puts("Digite um valor para b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("%d", Comparacao(a, b));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rDrpFQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xcxbqwda-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Compare.c).

Não precisa usar um `if` para realizar uma ação . Um `if` não serve para comparar algo, ele serve para realizar uma ação condicionalmente, você só precisa de um resultado e não uma ação, use o resultado. Preferi usar um operador condicional porque só lida com resultados.

Eu acho estranho retornar esses valores, mas não vou questionar o exercício. Ou você interpretou errado o que fazer. Eu acho mais intuitivo fazer dar -1 para números negativos, 0 para o 0 e 1 para os positivos. E tem outras formas de fazer isso, mas não acho que seja objetivo do exercício.

Nem precisei fazer outro condicional no final porque o resultado de um operador de comparação é 0 se der falso e 1 se der verdadeiro, e é este valores que deseja, então já uso o resultado sem estabelecer um outro resultado.

Comment: Caso não tenha familiaridade com operador condicional, vale checar: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/

Comment: Entendi Maniero, muito grato pela sua ajuda!

Comment: @RubenFontes veja o [tour], lá ensina a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.